# how to set input text automatically require when the certain radio button i checked

Tags: jquery, html

how to make input text required when im checked option1 radio button did i need to set value for each radio button and when im checked option2 the input text will not required

```
     <input type="radio"  name="ladder" value="ans1">
     <label for="option1">Option1</label><br>

     <input type="radio"  name="ladder" value="ans2">
     <label for="option2">Option2</label><br>

     <input type="text" name="ladder-meters" id="ladder-meters">
```

below is the javascript coding

```
 <script>
    $('input[name="ladder"]').change(function () {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#ladder-meters').attr('required');
        } else {
            $('#ladder-meters').removeAttr('required');
        }
    });
<script>
```

those coding basically not mine . im take it from other ppl in stackoveflow but they using this code successfully but when im try it doesnt work

Comment: You forgot a closing paranthesis in `if condition`

Comment: First, that's jQuery code, so won't work if you don't include jquery.js on your page before that code. Second, you need to change the first selector to `$('input[name="ladder"]')`, because the current selector of `"#ladder"` is looking for an element with `id="ladder"` (which doesn't exist).

Comment: i already add  if() condition and already  include jquery.js  and $('input[name="ladder"]') but still doesnt work

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking tick sign :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use jQuery and attributes that only have two values (on and off), you should use the [prop() function](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value). In your case it will be:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#ladder-meters').prop('required', true);
} else {
    $('#ladder-meters').prop('required', false);
}
```

Or, if you want to save a couple of lines:

```
var required = $(this).is(':checked');

$('#ladder-meters').prop('required', required);
```

EDIT:

In your case, there is also a problem with your `if` condition. You should check for current value of your radio button element, like so:

```
$('[name=ladder]').change(function() {
    var required = ($(this).val() === 'ans1');

    $('#ladder-meters').prop('required', required);
});
```

See this example on [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/parrker/pen/RVxxaq).

Comment: @LokmanHakim I added some changes, and an example on CodePen, it should work now.